# Segmentation fault: 11 error ( OpenCV )

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I've installed OpenCV, numpy and all other required contents using `brew install opencv`.

Then I tried running it `python >> import cv` or `python >> import cv2` but I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" error. [Crash Log](http://pastebin.com/UX66Hb4f)

Comment: Segmentation fault means that you're accessing some memory location that you're not supposed to, that that location is reserved for someone else. I don't know about OpenCV but are you sure isn't there some other intermediary step(s).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669587/python-segmentation-fault-11-when-running-import-cv-or-import-cv2. 
Did you install python through brew? If yes then there is probably crash between built-in version that ships with macOS and that installed through brew. Try using absolute path `/usr/bin/python -c "import cv2"` (built-in) and `/usr/local/bin/python -c "import cv"` (from brew). One should probably work.